# CSS3 Animation Repeat pause before next iteration

Tags: css, animation

I have a page with an image as a link that fades in and out and repeats infinitely. I would like to increase the time between iterations of the animations, a pause, if you will. I don't want the image to blink on and off, but fade in and out and then stay away for a while, then come back as a reminder. I would also like the animation to not start (i.e. the image is not visible on page load) for several seconds after the page loads. Is this possible using CSS only?

```
.click {margin-left: 26%;
  -webkit-animation: clickMe 4.5s ease-in-out 3s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    clickMe 4.5s ease-in-out 3s infinite;  /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      clickMe 4.5s ease-in-out 3s infinite;  /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         clickMe 4.5s ease-in-out 3s infinite;  /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */}

@-webkit-keyframes clickMe {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  50%  { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }

}
@-moz-keyframes clickMe {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  50%  { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-o-keyframes clickMe {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  50%  { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes clickMe {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  50%  { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the linked thread, `animation-delay` (which you have used in your snippet) introduces a delay only for the first cycle. To add delay for subsequent cycles you need to modify the keyframes like mentioned there.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other question @Harry. This helped me get a better understanding of how keyframes work, and now I have my animation working just the way I want it.